# Distorted mesh with bones

Tags: three.js, gltf

I have a question with my test model for experimenting blender 2.8 and gltf. It has a few bones but stays very simple. AFter loading into my three.js platform it looks OK (right on image) but rotation for some bones are wrong. I checked with the gltf viewer and got a worse result : obj is distorded:
http://lu-e-lou.com/priv/testmodel.jpg (on the left). 
model is here : http://lu-e-lou.com/priv/cylinder.zip 
Could you please help ?

three.js r104 - blender 2.80

Comment: I've tested your asset in the mentioned `glTF` viewer, with Babylon JS (https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/) and at Sketchfab(https://sketchfab.com). No viewer is able to render your file correctly. Looks like you are doing something wrong when exporting the model. Can you also share your `BLEND` file?

Comment: I tried to clean (rename bones properly and symmetrically) but it's the same.... http://lu-e-lou.com/priv/cylinder_28_v0b.blend

Comment: I've downloaded the latest Blender 2.8 version, exported the entire scene and imported it into `gltf-viewer`. The result looks good (see https://imgur.com/a/ExugFeo).

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry ; I was not with the latest 2.8 beta .... when scratching head to hard we forget the most basic things ... It work fine. Thanks a lot.